# How to force a runtime constant to be a compile time constant?

Tags: c#

So I am working on a chemistry based project and ran into this tricky problem. I have a bunch of functions doing chemistry type calculations and want to pass avogadros number as a default parameter for a function. Let me just let the code talk:

```
class Constants 
{
    //must be readonly to b/c Math.Pow is calculated at run-time
    public static double readonly avogadrosNum = 6.022*Math.Pow(10,-22);
} 

class chemCalculations
{   //getting default parameter must be a compile-time constant
    public double genericCalc(double avogadrosNum = Constants.avogadrosNum);  
}
```

Edit: was unaware of exponential format, thanks guys

Comment: Why don't you precalculate the result instead of calling pow and then use const?

Comment: It is a wasted microwatt.  Think of the future.

Comment: @DanielS. If you mean precalculate the result using Math.Pow and store it into a variable, I tried that and it didnt work because Math.Pow is not calculated until runtime

Comment: I meant carrying out the calculation and hardcoding the result.  Essentially, what everyone else suggested.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't, in general. Anything which involves a method call is *not* going to be a compile-time constant, as far as the compiler is concerned.

What you *can* do is express a `double` literal using scientific notation though:

```
public const double AvogadrosNumber = 6.022e-22;
```

So in *this specific case* you can write it with no loss of readability.

In other settings, so long as the type is one of the primitive types or `decimal`, you can just write out the constant as a literal, and use a comment to explain how you got it. For example:

```
// Math.Sqrt(Math.PI)
public const double SquareRootOfPi = 1.7724538509055159;
```

Note that even though method calls can't be used in constant expressions, other operators can. For example:

```
// This is fine
public const double PiSquared = Math.PI * Math.PI;

// This is invalid
public const double PiSquared = Math.Pow(Math.PI, 2);
```

See section 7.19 of the C# 5 specification for more details about what is allowed within a constant expression.

Comment: What's great about this answer is that you knew off the exact section of the C# spec that told you about `const` expressions and wrote an accepted answer about it without having to edit and did it within 5 minutes.

Comment: @dudeprgm: I suspect I *did* edit it, but within the 5 minute grace period, to be fair :)

Answer (score 2):

Just define avogadros number as scientific notation:

```
class Constants 
{
    public double const avogadrosNum = 6.022e-22;
}
```

Comment: `const` field cannot be marked static. This won't compile.

Answer (score 2):

For a compile-time constant, you need to use the `const` keyword. But, to use it, your expression itself needs to be a compile-time constant too, as you noticed: you cannot use functions such as `Math.Pow`.

```
class Constants
{
    public const double avogadrosNum = 6.022E-22;
}
```

If you cannot or do not want to rework your constant to a compile-time constant, you cannot use it in compile-time contexts, but you could work around that by overloading, so that a runtime value can be used as *sort of* a default argument:

```
class chemCalculations
{
    public double genericCalc() {
        return genericCalc(Constants.avogadrosNum);
    }
    public double genericCalc(double avogadrosNum) {
        // real code here
    }
}
```

(By the way, the value of the constant is either wrong, or has a highly misleading name. It should most likely be `6.022E+23`.)

Comment: Good catch, on the "+23". did not even realize that

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in exponential format: `6.022E-22`