# How can I define mathematical constants without typing out the number?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to use the square root of two, 1.414..., in a loop.

Obviously, I don't want to call the function Math.Sqrt(2) all the time.  Sure, it's a single instruction on modern processors, and the JIT or compiler will probably figure out what's going on, but I want my code to be clear, readable, and fast.

Because I want my code to be clear and readable, I'd prefer to define this constant by calling `sqrt2 = Math.Sqrt(2)` instead of typing in the magic number `sqrt2 = 1.4142135623731d`.

Finally, because this value is a constant, I want to declare it with the `const` keyword.  But when I write:

```
const double sqrt2 = Math.Sqrt(2);
// const double sqrt2 = 1.4142135623731d;
```

the compiler complains:

> Error 1   The expression being assigned to 'sqrt2' must be constant

How do I best define this value?

Comment: You get *that* compiler error from *that* code?

Comment: Hmm, something is wrong here. That code should not be generating a compiler error. Double literals are allowed, and they are obviously constant.

Comment: Strongly related: [How to force a runtime constant to be a compile time constant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501470/how-to-force-a-runtime-constant-to-be-a-compile-time-constant)

Comment: @Cody - If I'd remembered that there were different runtime constants and compile-time constants, I'd have found that question and answer.  We can close this as a dupe if you like, though I think it generated good answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Math.Sqrt` is a method call, so that cannot be assigned to a **compile-time** constant.
You can only assign it to a **run-time constant**:

```
static readonly double sqrt2 = Math.Sqrt(2);
```

Comment: I'd struggled with the difference between `const` and `static readonly` enough that I simply stopped using `static readonly`.  That makes sense!

Answer (score 7):

You can try to use `static readonly` instead of `const`.

```
static readonly double sqrt2 = Math.Sqrt(2);
```

Do understand that when you declare a constant then it has to be compile time constants.

The [C# spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx) says:

> A constant expression is an expression that can be fully evaluated at
>   compile time.

Answer (score 1):

In C# constant initializer must be compile const because they are embedded as literals in place of usage during compilation. This means that every usage of a member marked as `const` will be replaced with its value during compilation, while readonly members will be resolved at run-time. You can use `static readonly` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason that you shouldn't initialise it as a constant.

In my opinion, if you use a named constant for a number, then that number is *not* a magic number.

You could create a MathematicalConstants class to hold that, and other values:

```
public static class MathematicalConstants
{
    public const double SQRT2 = 1.4142135623731d;
    public const double SQRT3 = 1.7320508075689d;
}
```

Then if you're using C#6 or later, you can put

```
using static MathematicalConstants;
```

at the start of your code module, and you wouldn't need to refer to it as `MathematicalConstants.SQRT2`. You could just use `SQRT2` in your code:

```
const double sin45 = 1/SQRT2;
const double tan30 = 1/SQRT3;
```

Incidentally, there's a precedent for putting constants in static classes. The `Math` class has `PI` and `E` as constants, and they are initialized directly in the source code.

Comment: ...which literally requires typing out the number - completely the opposite of what was asked for.

Comment: @Wyck You are mistaken. At the call site, you would use SQRT2 as per my example at the end of my answer, e.g. `const double sin45 = 1/SQRT2;` - as you can see, that does NOT involve typing out the number. I think you are confusing the point of use with the initialisation. You initialise it once, and use it many times. This is in fact what Microsoft do for the definition of [`Math.PI`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pi?view=net-6.0)

Comment: I understand you.  But you can't deny that you gave SQRT2 its value by typing out the number.