# Are arithmetic operations on literals in C++ evaluated at compile time?

Tags: c++

Herein, similar questions were asked for `C#`:

[Are arithmetic operations on literals in C# evaluated at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451656/are-arithmetic-operations-on-literals-in-c-sharp-evaluated-at-compile-time),

and `java`:

[Are arithmetic operations on literals calculated at compile time or run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33040680/are-arithmetic-operations-on-literals-calculated-at-compile-time-or-run-time).

**Considering C++, will the following calculations be evaluated during run- or compile-time?** The first is to define a built-in type, the second is to be a function argument.

Yet please consider them for all 4 basic arithmetic operations as well as with other built-in types, e.g. an `int` instead of the `double` below.

- `double testDouble = 2.0 + 2.0;`
- `aUserDefinedType testUserDefinedTypeObject
  (
      aMemberVariable*std::pow(someOtherVariable, 1.0/8.0)
  );`

Comment: [Go ahead and find out](https://godbolt.org/). It's not required, an optimizing compiler might/will do it.

Comment: Constant arithmetic expressions such as `2.0 + 2.0` might or might not be evaluated during compile time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on your compiler and its optimization level when building the code.

There is no intrinsic *guarantee* of compile time evaluation, but most compilers will evaluate constant expressions at compile time when optimizations are turned on.

There is also [constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) which can also help the compiler know what can be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: Accordingly, I presume that it is always recommended to evaluate such expressions beforehand, and not to leave this to the compiler's preference? e.g. instead of  `1.0/8.0`, writing `0.125` is always preferable? Please consider this in the context of very high number of FLOPT computations.

Comment: @Kuti any modern optimizing compiler *will* evaluate trivial expressions like that at compile time as soon as optimizations are turned on. You should write the code in the way that makes it the most clear and trust the optimizer (it's smarter than you) - readability counts for *a lot* and micro-optimization like that that the compiler does *anyway* will just hurt readability.

Comment: The conformance parameters of the compiler matter. An exact operation like 1./8. is always fine, but for instance 1./3. depends on the rounding mode and thus cannot be evaluated at compile-time when compilers support rounding modes (-frounding-math for gcc).