# Can C++ compiler calculate division result of literals during the compile time

Tags: c++

I have next code:

```
#define TIMEOUT_MS = 10000

class Data
{
public:
    Data()
    : _timeoutMs{TIMEOUT_MS / 1000} // Сan С++ standard guarantee that division will be calculated during the compile time?
    {
    }
private:
    int _timeoutMs = 0;
};
```

Please see question in the comment.

Comment: you can always enforce it by using `constexpr`

Comment: It doesn’t have to in your code.

Comment: [*Constant folding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) is a very common and also very simple optimization. The chances of you using a compiler not doing it is slim to none. However, it's not something that's guaranteed by the C++ specification.

Comment: @VTT I slightly simplified code. Actually struct is external code and I initialize this field in my custom function: d._timeoutMs = TIMEOUT_MS / 1000.

Comment: Your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48851994/12188799

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO C++ forum. Your question is OK, it touches on C++ "standard" vs compilers "de-facto standards" issue. In this instance the later prevails.

I will be so bold to present variant of your code transformed into standard C++

```
// g++ prog.cc -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
 // this will not compile
 // #define TIMEOUT_MS = 10000
 // this will
 // #define TIMEOUT_MS 10000
 // but avoid macros whenever you can
 // constexpr guarantees compile time values
   constexpr 
    auto TIMEOUT_MS{ 10000U } ;

  // always use namespaces to avoid name clashes 
  namespace igor {
  // 'struct' is comfortable choice for private types
   // 'final' makes for (even) more optimizations
   struct data final
   {
     // standard C++ generates this for you
     // data()   {  }

     // do not start a name with underscore
     // https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/10870835
      constexpr static auto timeout_ = TIMEOUT_MS / 1000U ;
  }; // data
} // igor ns

 int main( int , char * [] )
 {
    using namespace std ;
    // for time related computing use <chrono>
    cout << boolalpha << igor::data::timeout_ << " s (perhaps)" << endl;
   return 42 ;
  }
```

Whenever you can post the link to your (short!) code that compiles and runs or just show the problem.

I use wandbox : https://wandbox.org/permlink/Fonz5ISoOL1KNJqe

Enjoy the standard C++.

Comment: `_timeoutMs` is fine since it is not in the global namespace. Otherwise, nice refactoring.

Comment: @Quentin thank's, although, I prefer my team not to do things standard does not allow, even they can be done in some context.

Comment: Well, only `::` is concerned, and since you're observing the "always namespace your code" rule it won't ever apply :)